# Google Cloud Storage Share Publicly

Tags: google-cloud-storage

My Acl permissions on my bucket are as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<AccessControlList>
    <Owner>
        <ID>00b4903a97dfaa16aff41eeb91e90b5fb524f1daf0d88fceca29b6f647412e8d</ID>
    </Owner>
    <Entries>
        <Entry>
            <Scope type="GroupById">
                <ID>00b4903a97dfaa16aff41eeb91e90b5fb524f1daf0d88fceca29b6f647412e8d</ID>
            </Scope>
            <Permission>FULL_CONTROL</Permission>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
            <Scope type="AllUsers"/>
            <Permission>READ</Permission>
        </Entry>

<Entry>
   <Scope type="UserByEmail">
      <EmailAddress>
         my_app@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
      </EmailAddress>
   </Scope>
   <Permission>
      WRITE
   </Permission>
</Entry>

    </Entries>
</AccessControlList>
```

But when i upload a new file in this bucket is not shared by default.

I think i should be because of the AllUsers permission set to read

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are confusing bucket permissions and object permissions. The bucket is publicly readable so everyone can list the contents of the bucket but the object you upload has its own set of permissions. If you want an uploaded object to be publicly readable you need to enable that explicitly. You could use the following command to do that:

```
gsutil setacl public-read gs://bucket/object
```

Alternatively, you could set the default object ACL for the containing bucket to be publicly readable, using this command:

```
gsutil setdefacl public-read gs://bucket
```

The advantage of the latter is that every object uploaded to that bucket will automatically inherit public readability from the containing bucket.

Comment: just `gsutil setacl public-read gs://bucket/object` doesn't work for me. it redirects to the google authentication page then and works as with AllAuthenticatedUsers permission

Comment: Can you share the output from gsutil getacl on the object and also the URL you are using to access the object?

Comment: Already solved, I've used the wrong url, with http://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/object it works fine, thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you get: You are using a deprecated alias, "setdefacl", for the "defacl" ...

Use `gsutil defacl set public-read gs://bucketname`