# Can't resolve Cloud Vision error - code 5 Error opening file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-vision

I'm using Cloud Vision on an image along with Nodejs, Firebase emulator and Firebase cloud functions. This is all happening in an https function.

The code:

```
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
const request = {
      image: {
        source: { imageUri: `gs://${bucketName}/${file.name}` },
      },
      features: [
        {
          type: "LABEL_DETECTION",
          maxResults: 50,
        },
        {
          maxResults: 10,
          type: "FACE_DETECTION",
        },
        {
          type: "LOGO_DETECTION",
        },
        {
          maxResults: 10,
          type: "OBJECT_LOCALIZATION",
        },
        {
          type: "SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION",
        },
        {
          type: "WEB_DETECTION",
        },
      ],
    };

const [result] = await client.annotateImage(request);

console.log("Result", result)
```

The `console.log` gives me this error.

> ```
>  error: {
>  details: [],
>  code: 5,
>  message: 'Error opening file: gs://myProjectID.appspot.com/File1/Screenshot 2023-06-19 at 11.38.07.png.'
>  }
> ```

Online i can't seem to find error code 5 specifically so i don't know what's wrong.
Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: bucketName seems to be myProjectID. I doubt that's correct. Make sure the file exists as the error states.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195006/google-cloud-vision-api-quickstart-error-opening-file?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, it turns out that i'm trying to read from Emulator storage but Cloud Vision is searching for it in my live environment.